# Line "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5" deleted from the pg_hba.conf file at the same time every day

Tags: django, postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I have added this line "`host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`" to my `pg_hba.conf` file to allow connections to my database.

Problem is that this line gets deleted around 13:07GMT everyday resulting in this error

```
"no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "****", database "****db", SSL off".
```

I don't know how and why the line gets deleted(looks the the `pg_hba.conf` is been re-configured to default)

I re-add the line to pg_hba.conf, restart postgres and the application works again.

How do i resolve this problem to keep that line in the file permanently?

I use (PostgreSQL) 8.4.20, Centos 6.8

I have also checked and can't find any cron job running around that time.

Please your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it on some hosting? or VM?..

Comment: Is this PostgreSQL installed via yum from CentOS? It is very out of date, so I’m guessing the answer is yes.

Comment: @VaoTsun yes it is hosting not VM

Comment: @FlipperPA yes it is installed via yum... your guess is right but is that related to the problem i am facing? Do i need to upgrade?

Comment: so call to hosting help center and address your question them :)

Comment: @VaoTsun its a vps and at their end all seem to be well when i mentioned this to them.

Comment: never heard of VPN rewriting files on your hosted OS... I think they lie. or you misunderstood?..